# How to pass parameters into subscription function?

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

There is a for loop to loop through an array, then calls a firestore get document operation. I would like to pass the value of i into the subscription function. How do I do this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
{
    let something = firebase.firestore().collection('someCollection').doc(this.someArray[i]);
    let something$ = Observable.create(something.onSnapshot.bind(something));
    let something$Subscription = something$.subscribe
    ({
        next: (snapshot: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) =>
        {
            console.log('inserted' + i)
            //how to pass the value of i from the for loop function into this async subscription.
        },
        error: (firestoreError: firebase.firestore.FirestoreError) =>
        {
            console.log(firestoreError);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Observable.create()` use `new Subject()` or `new BehaviorSubject(initialValue)`.

Then you can do `something$.next(nextValue)`